# Embed option is not available in Grafana

Tags: user-interface, web, embed, grafana

I want to embed Grafana dashboard in custom UI.  i followed below guide to enable embed option in Grafana.
https://www.itpanther.com/embedding-grafana-in-iframe/

After enabling below settings also i am not able to find Embed option in Grafana-

```
allow_embedding = true
auth.anonymous
enabled = true
org_name = <<org name>>
org_role = Viewer
```

[image]

Please guide me how can i enable & see Embed option in Grafana server?

Comment: What grafana version is being used?

Comment: @rohatgisanat  i am using v7.1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The export option is available out of the box in Grafana v7.1.5
[image: embedded]